# Complicated Nonlinear system Numerical differentiating

Tags: matlab

I have a nonlinear steady space matrix.I need to solve the differential as shown in the pic below: 
I explained more on pic(Here `dD/dx`)

[image]

Comment: Are you supposed to find the Jacobian? Gradient?  I don't understand what `dD/dx` means in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do symbolic differentation with the MATLAB Symbolic Toolbox, but you have to tell it to perform the right partial derivatives.  Your dependent variable (x) has three components, so you cannot take the partial derivative of D with respect to x, but you can take the partial derivative with respect to x1, x2, and x3.

```
 syms t x1 x2 x3  x1_dot x2_dot x3_dot

 x1_dot = diff(x1, t)
 x2_dot = diff(x2, t)
 x3_dot = diff(x3, t)
 D(x1,x2,x3) = [... your function matrix ... ]
 dD_x1 = diff(D,x1)
 dD_x2 = diff(D,x2)
 dD_x3 = diff(D,x3)
```